# How do you programmatically reload a jquery datatable?

Tags: datatables

I have a jquery datatable on a page that I want to reload after a user action.  Also, I do not set the `ajax` parameter on my datatable because the url is always changing and I need to process the JSON data a bit after I get it.

Here is my code to initially set the datatable.

```js
$.getJSON(uri, function (people) {
        // ... code removed for brevity ...
        $("#people-table").dataTable({
            "data": people,
            "columns": [{
                "data": "id",
                "title": "Id"
            }, {
                "data": "full_name",
                "title": "Name"
            }, {
                "data": "phone",
                "title": "Home Phone"
            }, {
                "data": "cell_phone",
                "title": "Mobile"
            }, {
                "data": "email",
                "title": "Email"
            }]
        });
```

How do I reload the table after a user action (like a button click)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you do it.

*(I would recommend only doing this if you must pre-process the JSON data before setting it into the datatable.  If you can use the datatable `ajax` parameter, that is preferable.)*

```js
        $.getJSON(uri, function(people) {
        // ... code removed for brevity ...
        if (if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#people-table"))) {
            var api = $("#people-table").dataTable().api();
            api.clear();
            people.forEach(function(row, idx) {
                api.row.add(row);
            });
            api.draw();
        } else {

            $("#people-table").dataTable({
                "data": people,
                "columns": [
                { "data": "id", "title": "Id" },
                { "data": "full_name", "title": "Name" },
                { "data": "phone", "title": "Home Phone" },
                { "data": "cell_phone", "title": "Mobile" },
                { "data": "email", "title": "Email" }
                ]
            });
        }
```

Comment: Aaaaand I'm about to refactor this code and rip it all out.  I can use the datatables `ajax` setting after all.  I can use the [`columnDefs`](http://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html) to do my data manipulation.  And I can use [`ajax.url()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url()) to change the URI.  Money!  Less is More!